# window.parent.focus() does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to return to my window opener page in Google Chrome. Focus worked some time ago, but now it doesn't. I use the latest version of Google Chrome (21.0.1180.75). I didn't find any reason or explanation of this bug on the internet. Window.opener.alert() is not an acceptable solution. Here is the code I currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin()
{

var params = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"
var wnd = window.open("about:_blank", "", params);

wnd.document.write("<input type='button' value='focus' onClick='window.opener.focus()'/>");

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it doesn't work - that's the problem!

Comment: It appears that `window.opener` doesn't apply to new tabs (which your code produces due to lack of height/width); only pop ups in the current version of Chrome. However, I made it a popup and tried a lot of variations to no avail.